# function to calculate the sum of odd numbers in a given stack

Tags: c#, data-structures, stack, sum

I now that this question it has been mada many  times but,
I need a function to calculate the sum of odd numbers in a given stack S

I have try something like this, but i now that it is not correct.

```
private static int Sum(int n, x)
{            

    if (n % 2 == 0) && (x % 2 == 0)
       return n + x;
}
```

Comment: i don't have my stack declared because this is only a school work for my friend and question was like that.

Comment: @ilirvg Then the first thing you should do is create a stack and put some numbers on it, so that you have something to test your function with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just an example, you could pass your stack variable as an argument to the `GetSum()` function.

```
private static int GetSum()
        {
              Stack<int> stack = new Stack<int>();

            stack.Push(2);
            stack.Push(5);
            stack.Push(7);
            stack.Push(4);
            stack.Push(1);

            int sum = 0;

            foreach (int number in stack)
            {
                if (number % 2 != 0)
                {
                    sum += number;
                }
            }

        return sum;
    }
```

Comment: I get the feeling you just did his homework

Comment: @cost we all do sometimes lol

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode:

1. declare int sum = 0
2. per each element in S, check if it is an odd number
3. if odd, add to sum

Comment: There is a distinct lack of LINQ here.